# Asp.net mvc issues loading a partial page into a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm struggling to get my head around this. I am attempting to load a partial view into a div for a modal but i just cant seem to get it working. Every time i click the button the screen fades as if its going to show a modal but then returns to normal. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Button

```html
<button class="btn btn-default" id="addDocument">Add</button>
```

The Empty Modal

```html
<div id='myModal' class='modal fade' data-url='@Url.Action("CreateTemplateDocument")'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my script

```js
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#addDocument').click(function () {
                var url = $('#myModal').data('url');

                $.get(url, function (data) {
                    $('#myModalContent').html(data);

                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Update:

So from doing further testing it seems that the page is reloading after running the script. I was under the impression that was what ajax prevented but im guessing that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by having the function return false. I'm not sure why this worked so if anyone could enlighten me, that would be awesome.

Answer (score -1):

Try this i have change the Modal show command and remove data url

```js
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#addDocument').click(function () {
                var url = $('#myModal').data('url');

                $.get(url, function (data) {
                    $('#myModalContent').html(data);

                    $('#myModal').modal({
            keyboard: false,
            remote: '/home/partial'    // YOUR PARTIAL VIEW URL
                   }).show();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

```html
<div id='myModal' class='modal fade' >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```html
<div id='myModal' class='modal fade' data-url='@Url.Action("CreateTemplateDocument")'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it has the same result as what i had.